# Problems in placing Buttons that stays at the bottom of the screen under the ListView in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to make a button that stays at the bottom of the screen for my application in Android Studio, which placed under a ListView object.

I try to use Relative Layout on the XML called *activity_puskesmas_main.xml* to place the button (generated automatically from my activity called **PuskesmasMain.java**), but all buttons struck down to the bottom left on my screen.

**This is the screenshot picture when I run the apps on AVD (also happens on my real device**
 [image: This is the screenshot picture when I run the apps on AVD (also happens on my real device)]

This is the XML code :

[Please click here to see my activity_puskesmas_main.xml code](https://anotepad.com/notes/78igpqh)

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >
</FrameLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:id="@+id/loadingBar"/>

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/cari"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >
</SearchView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDaftar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnHome"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
            android:text="Halaman Utama"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPuskesmas"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/puskesmasview"
            android:text="Puskesmas"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPenyakit"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/penyakitview"
            android:text="Penyakit"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEmergency"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/emergencyview"
            android:text="Telepon Darurat"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have no idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want your buttons below the list view, or on top of it,but anchored to the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You want to fix it in the footer of the list view. So, You can use the property of the listview that if `footerview`

like this

```
 //code to set adapter to populate list
        View footerView =  ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
        list.addFooterView(footerView);
```

You can create new layout `footer_layout` and put the relative layout code inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your layout to have the button bar anchored to the bottom, the search bar at the top and the list view in between, then you constrain the search bar to the top like you did. Constrain the button bar to the bottom with `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` and you constraint the list view between them with `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cari"` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_bar"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".PuskesmasMain">


   <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/frame"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
         android:background="@android:color/background_light"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         >

   </FrameLayout>

   <ProgressBar
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         android:visibility="invisible"
         android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
         style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
         android:id="@+id/loadingBar"/>

   <SearchView
         android:id="@+id/cari"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         >

   </SearchView>

   <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listViewDaftar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cari"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_bar"
         >

   </ListView>



   <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/button_bar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:baselineAligned="false"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
         android:gravity="bottom"
         >



         <Button
               android:id="@+id/btnHome"
               style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
               android:layout_width="90dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_margin="5dp"
               android:drawableTop="@drawable/home"
               android:text="Halaman Utama"
               />

         <Button
               android:id="@+id/btnPuskesmas"
               style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
               android:layout_width="110dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_margin="5dp"
               android:drawableTop="@drawable/puskesmasview"
               android:text="Puskesmas"

               />

         <Button
               android:id="@+id/btnPenyakit"
               style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
               android:layout_width="95dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_margin="5dp"
               android:drawableTop="@drawable/penyakitview"
               android:text="Penyakit"
               />

         <Button
               android:id="@+id/btnEmergency"
               style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
               android:layout_width="90dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_margin="5dp"
               android:drawableTop="@drawable/emergencyview"
               android:text="Telepon Darurat"
               />


   </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```